# BlueZ - How to get number / list of available bluetooth adapters

Tags: c++, bluez

How can I get a list of the available bluetooth adapters from BlueZ using C++? I'm specifically trying to use `bluetooth/bluetooth.h`, `bluetooth/hci.h`, as opposed to the DBUS API as I need to connect directly to the HCI sockets.

Ideally I want the number of adapters, their ids (e.g. `hci0`, `hci1`, etc), their addresses, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an example of accomplishing this in the `find_controllers` function at [bluez/tools/cltest.c](https://github.com/bluez/bluez/blob/master/tools/cltest.c) which I've expanded below to include the address of the adapters

```cpp
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci_lib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int main()
{
    // Create a hci socket
    int hciSocket = hci_open_dev(hci_get_route(NULL));
    if (hciSocket < 0)
    {
        perror("Failed to open HCI device");
        return 1;
    }

    // Create int and pointers to hold results for later
    int devCount;
    struct hci_dev_list_req *devList;
    struct hci_dev_info devInfo;

    // Allocate memory for devList pointer. Based on HCI_MAX_DEV (maximum number of HCI devices) multiplied by the size of struct hci_dev_req, plus the size of uint16_t (to store the device number)
    devList = (struct hci_dev_list_req *)malloc(HCI_MAX_DEV * sizeof(struct hci_dev_req) + sizeof(uint16_t));
    if (!devList)
    {
        perror("Failed to allocate HCI device request memory");
        close(hciSocket);
        return 1;
    }

    // Honestly not sure why we have to do this here?
    devList->dev_num = HCI_MAX_DEV;

    // Send the HCIGETDEVLIST command to get the device list.
    if (ioctl(hciSocket, HCIGETDEVLIST, (void *)devList) < 0)
    {
        perror("Failed to get HCI device list");
        free(devList);
        close(hciSocket);
        return 1;
    }

    // 
    devCount = devList->dev_num;
    std::cout << "Found " << devCount << " HCI devices" << std::endl;

    // Iterate over the devices and retrieve information
    for (int i = 0; i < devCount; i++) {
        // Set the device ID for device info retrieval
        devInfo.dev_id = devList->dev_req[i].dev_id;
        if (ioctl(hciSocket, HCIGETDEVINFO, (void *)&devInfo) < 0) {
            perror("Failed to get HCI device info");
            continue;
        }

        char addr[18];
        ba2str(&devInfo.bdaddr, addr);

        // Print device information
        std::cout << "HCI Device " << i + 1 << ":" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "  Address: " << addr << std::endl;
        std::cout << "  Dev ID: " << devInfo.dev_id << std::endl;
        std::cout << "  Flags: 0x" << std::hex << devInfo.flags << std::dec << std::endl;
        std::cout << "  Type: 0x" << std::hex << devInfo.type << std::dec << std::endl;
    }

    free(devList);
    close(hciSocket);

    return 0;
}
```